# How to send complex JSON in HTTP GET request

Tags: api, rest, http, post, get

I know sending JSON body in get request is violating http rules, however in my case I need to send a JSON object contains filter criteria. This JSON object has many fields and nested JSON values. Is it ok to choose the http method for this API as POST and send the filter object in body?